# Using vue slots in library gives currentRenderingInstance is null

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, rollup

I am creating a Vue component library with Rollup, but when I use slots it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: currentRenderingInstance is null

I made a very simple component in my library:

```html
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <button>
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

Then I simply use it like this:

```html
<ExampleComponent>
  Text
</ExampleComponent>
```

If I remove the slot and replace it with a prop or hard-coded text, everything works fine.

This is my `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'rollup';
import path from 'path';

import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';

// the base configuration
const baseConfig = {
  input: 'src/entry.js',
};

// plugins
const plugins = [
  vue(),
  resolve({
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
  }),
  // process only `<style module>` blocks.
  postcss({
    modules: {
      generateScopedName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    },
    include: /&module=.*\.css$/,
  }),
  // process all `<style>` blocks except `<style module>`.
  postcss({ include: /(?<!&module=.*)\.css$/ }),
  commonjs(),
];

const external = ['vue'];
const globals = {
  vue: 'Vue',
};

export default [
  // esm
  defineConfig({
    ...baseConfig,
    input: 'src/entry.esm.js',
    external,
    output: {
      file: 'dist/vue-my-lib.esm.js',
      format: 'esm',
      exports: 'named',
    },
    plugins,
  }),

  // cjs
  defineConfig({
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/vue-my-lib.ssr.js',
      format: 'cjs',
      name: 'VueMyLib',
      exports: 'auto',
      globals,
    },
    plugins,
  }),

  // iife
  defineConfig({
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/vue-my-lib.min.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'VueMyLib',
      exports: 'auto',
      globals,
    },
    plugins,
  }),
];
```

Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Is Vue definitely being loaded in correctly in your built app?

Comment: @Lissy93 I tested it in a brand-new project (using vue-cli, because in the other project I was using Jetstream + Inertia) and I have the same problem using slots. But actually, I don't really know how to check if Vue is loaded correctly. I have no errors or warnings, so I assume it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a whole day of searching, I found the solution ([here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4478) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344)). It's a problem with using a library locally (e.g., through `npm link`) where it seems there are two instances of Vue at the same time (one of the project and one of the library). So, the solution is to tell the project to use specifically its own vue through webpack.

In my case, I use Jetstream + Inertia, so I edited `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

// ...

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        alias: {
            vue: path.resolve("./node_modules/vue"),
        },
    },
});
```

Or if you used `vue-cli` to create your project, edit the `vue.config.js`:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = defineConfig({

  // ...

  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false);
    config.resolve.alias.set("vue", path.resolve("./node_modules/vue"));
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mikelplhts

On vite + esbuild I used:

```
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            ...
            {
                find: 'vue',
                replacement: path.resolve("./node_modules/vue"),
            },
        ],
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with rollup too.

Just to add in the external config

```
const external = [
  { vue: path.resolve('./node_modules/vue') },
];
```

````
const unpkgConfig = {
    ...,
    output: {
      ....
    },
    external,
    ...
```
````